# Passing label data from one view controller to the other

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my first view controller, a label shows the answer to the equation inputted by the user. When the user goes to the next view controller, I'd like the label in the second view controller to have the same data as received in the first one. I have read through a lot of passing data articles and questions on the internet (including here on SO). None seem to fall under my problem.

For example, I have 2 text fields and a label in my first view controller. If the user puts the number 2 in both fields, the label will show 4 as the answer. I'd then like the answer shown in the label to be available when the user goes on to the next view controller which explains the answer in depth.

**EDIT:** I'll put this in terms of my project so I can understand it better. I really appreciate all the responses!

In my first view controller named 'View Controller', the user calculates their BMI which shows up in a label known as 'bmiView'.

In my second view controller (TipsViewController), it shows the classification of the user. For example, if in the users calculated BMI from the first view controller is 30.00 they are classified as 'Obese' which I would like to show in the second view controller.

Comment: This is a very basic functionality you are asking. Create a string property in your second viewController. While instantiating that vc set the text of label to that string property. On viewDidLoad of second vc set the value of string to the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **FirstViewController** suppose you have a `UILabel *myLabel`

```
myLabel.text =@"Hari kishan ";
```

**SecondviewController**
and you have another label in second view controller.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *secondLabel;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *secondLabelText; //a string to contain text for that Label

//To set text of secondLabel as mylabel 
//do this in **FirstViewController.m**

SecondvViewController *objSecondviewController =[[SecondviewController alloc]init];
objSecondviewController.secondLabelText=myLabel.text;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecondviewController animated:YES];
```

Now In **SecondvViewController.m**

```
self.secondLabel.text=secondLabelText;
```

Comment: Property 'text' not found on object of type  'NSString'        how we can set self.secondLabel.text=secondLabelText; as it is string?

Answer (score 0):

**FirstController**

```
-(void)calculateAnswer{
    int answer=[self.firstInput.text intValue] + self.secondInput.text intValue];

    SecondController *controller=[[SecondController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    //Answer is a PUBLIC property declared in SecondController
    controller.answer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",answer];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

**SecondController**

**In SecondController.h**

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *answer;
```

**In SecondController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.lblAnswer.text=self.answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in view controller 2 make a property of string

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * resultValue;
```

in viewdidLoad

```
[self.textfieldOutlet setText:self.resultValue];
```

When initializing 2nd View controller

```
Viewcontroller2 *val=[Viewcontroller2 alloc ]init];
val.resultValue = self.resulttextFieldoutletinVC1.text;
```

push/modal the viewcontroller

So just pass the value in a string and you have the value in the 2nd view controller and do whatever logic on it

Comment: But I don't want the data from the Text Field to pass to my next view controller, I want the data from the label to be passed. Are labels capable of storing data?

Comment: @LoganLarroque : labels are capable of storing data but if you drectly pass the value to label ,it wont work ,since label is loaded from xib it wont have a valid memory there,So use a string to store the value and set it in the next VC viewdidLoad

Answer (score 0):

You can create property of string in secondView

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *strResultedText;
@end
```

than you can pass your label's value to second view from first before pushing or presenting. You can access the property using the SecondView's object like:

```
SecondViewController *obj = //your initialization
obj.strResultedText = lbl.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Steps :

**1) Create Property called `final` in Next View Controller :**

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *final;
```

**2) Calculate the Sum :**

```
int firstVal = [yourFirstTextField.text intValue];
int secondVal = [yourSecondTextField.text intValue];
int resultVal = firstVal + secondVal;
NSString *final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",resultVal];
```

**3) Send it to Next View Controller :**

```
NextViewController *navController = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
nextViewObj.final = final;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

**4) In Next View Controller :**

```
yourLabel.text = self.final;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NSString` named `labelText` in your `SecondViewController.h` and let the name of your label in `FirstViewController` be `myLabel` then do this in your 'FirstViewController' :

```
SecondViewController *view = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
view.labelText = myLabel.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults. 
In first view controller if your label value is changed you can save value:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: label.text
                                          forKey: @"lableValue"];
```

in second view controller:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
     label.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey: @"lableValue"];
}
```